# How to add elements in an object while traversing through an array using map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I am having an array like this :
`arr =  [ {id:0,name:Mark} , {id:1,name:Ron}, {id:2,name:Henry}, {id:3,name:Rose}]`.

I want to create an object like this :

`obj1 = { Mark:false, Ron:false, Henry:false, Rose:flase }`

I am using `map` to traverse through the array like this

```
let obj1 = {};
obj1 = arr.map((item)=> {
    obj1[item.name] = false;
  })
```

How can I achieve the following result?

Comment: Remove `obj1 = ` infront of `arr.map` and then change the `.map()` to `.forEach()` to avoid [misusing `.map()`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map entries and build an object from the pairs.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 0, name: 'Mark' }, { id: 1, name: 'Ron' }, { id: 2, name: 'Henry' }, { id: 3, name: 'Rose' }],
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({ name }) => [name, false]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And suppose I had an `obj1 = { Default: false}` as initially defined, then how can I get the obj like `{ Default:false, Mark:false, Ron:false, Henry:false, Rose:flase }`

Comment: you can add it later to the object (order does not matter in objects, usually). or create a new one with spreading the object from the array, like `object = { Default: false, ...result }`;

Answer (score 1):

`Object.fromEntries()` is probably the best idea. But you could also use reduce, if you got more operations on the array and want to stick to the "pipe" approach.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Mark' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Ron' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Henry' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Rose' }
];

const objA = arr
  .reduce((previous, { name }) => ({ ...previous, [name]: false }), {});

const objB = arr
  .reduce((previous, { name }) => {
    previous[name] = false;
    return previous;
  }, {});
```

The spreach operation [`{...obj}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) for `objA` does effectivly copy the object on each extension, which might not be desirable. But the modern JavaScript engines simplify those expressions anyways.

`objB` is the more standard approach for me. One additional benefit, in regards to `Object.fromEntries()` is that you can have some form of standard or default object / settings, which you can use as the start of the reduce (the second parameter) and evaluate in the collection function.

All three options are valid and depend on your code style.

Comment: And suppose I had an `obj1 = { Default: false}` as initially defined, then how can I get the obj like `{ Default:false, Mark:false, Ron:false, Henry:false, Rose:flase }`

Comment: @MagnusEffect you can add it as the second parameter to the `reduce` (`.reduce(,{Default: false})`). Just keep in mind that lowercase `default` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript and should not be used.